# Prototype for template instantiation?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a type `VertexContainer` which is a typedef'ed instantiated template:

```
// in a header, included into cpp
class Vertex {/*...*/};
typedef DataVector<Vertex> VertexContainer;

class SomeOtherClass;
```

I would like to use `VertexContainer` in a header, without pulling in the definition of possible. Is it possible to create a "prototype" (like a class declaration) for it?

```
// in header
class VertexContainer;  // <-- this doesnt work
class SomeOtherClass;

SomeHandle<SomeOtherClass> handle1;   // this works
SomeHandle<VertexContainer> handle2;  // how to prototype VertexContainer?
```

With GCC I get an error similar to:

```
error: using typedef-name 'VertexContainer' after 'class'
   class VertexContainer;
(...)
note: 'VertexContainer' has a previous declaration here
    typedef DataVector< Vertex > VertexContainer;
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`
```

Comment: You cannot forward declare `typedef`.

Answer (score 5):

For an authoritative answer, you should provide more context, but in general the following will compile, if placed by itself in a header:

```
template<typename T> class DataVector;
class Vertex;

typedef DataVector<Vertex> VertexContainer;
```

You need to forward-declare both the template, and the class. However, by the time you get here:

```
SomeHandle<VertexContainer> handle2;
```

Both the template and possibly the class (depending on how the template uses the class) will need to be fully defined. It's not possible to determine that without additional context in your question.

But, purely as a forward declaration, forward-declaring the template and the template parameter is sufficient for defining the `typedef`.

Furthermore:

```
class VertexContainer;
```

Your error on that line has a slightly different reason. `VertexContaner` is not a class. It is a `typedef`, an alias. A `typedef` does not create a new class. It creates an alias for an existing class.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that you could forward-declare template classes (your first code line). `SomeHandle` is just a placeholder here. The actual code just creates a pointer under to hood I think, so I thought it should work with any type. I know `VertexContainer` is not a class, but `DataVector<Vertex>` is in a way, so I was looking for a way to tell the compiler "calm down, VertexContainer (alias DataVector<Vertex>) is something you can plug into the SomeHandle template, and don't need to know it's definition until later".

Comment: I tried it, but this "forward-declared" VertexContainer seems to conflict with the actual VertexContainer. I get a "conflicting declaration" error. It works however if I include the actual definition of DataVector... I think it might not be worth it, and I might just include the header and skip the forward-declaration idea.

Answer (score 0):

Templates are just a clever way for code substitution.

So in order to be able to use a forward declaration of the type, like with any other forward declaration you are only allowed to use the type inside of the templated container in a way, that the declaration has never to be known.

So only pointers and references to your `Vertex` are allowed inside of `DataVector`, if you do not want pull in the declaration.